# Adjust gridview rowIndex when programmatically adding new row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, indexing

I've seen this article http://asp.net-informations.com/gridview/newrow.htm and this post http://forums.asp.net/p/1534978/3725419.aspx#3725419 and I've done it for have that separator row collapsible with jquery and it's working great in display mode. The problems occuring when try to do something else with gridview, because there's a weird behaviour.. I've add a simple button that have just to set a radiobutton that's in every gridview row (except in the new added GroupHeaders rows). Then if I have added two new row he is skipping setting the last two rows in the GridView..

```
    public void AddNewRow(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView GridView1 = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow NewTotalRow = new GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "collapsible('" + rowgroup + "')");
        NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
        TableCell HeaderCellIndex = new TableCell();
        int indexCorrente = e.Row.RowIndex + index;
        HeaderCellIndex.Text = indexCorrente.ToString();
        NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCellIndex);
        GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.Add(NewTotalRow);
    }

    protected void gdDettaglio_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        bool newRow = false;
        if ((DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Stato") != null))
        {
            if (statoCorrente != Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Stato").ToString()))
                newRow = true;
        }
        if (newRow)
        {
            AddNewRow(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

Printing the row index (just to check it) next to each row I'm displaying this situation (with two GroupHeader rows added):

(The index are as they are printing them in gdDettaglio_RowCreated for GroupHeadrs rows and on gdDettaglio_OnDataBound for the other rows)

```
-----------------------------------------
|           HEADER                      |
|---------------------------------------|
-----------------------------------------
|           Gruppo 1        |  index -1  |
|---------------------------------------|
|   grp1 | x | blablabla |  |  index 0  |
|   grp1 | y | blablabla |  |  index 1  |
|   grp1 | z | blablabla |  |  index 2  |
|   grp1 | x | blablabla |  |  index 3  |
|   grp1 | x | blablabla |  |  index 4  |
|---------------------------------------|
|           Gruppo 2        |  index -1  |
|---------------------------------------|
|   grp2 | x | blablabla |  |  index 5  |
|   grp2 | y | blablabla |  |  index 6  |
|   grp2 | z | blablabla |  |  index 7  |
|   grp2 | z | blablabla |  |  index 8  |
|   grp2 | z | blablabla |  |  index 9  |
|   grp2 | z | blablabla |  |  index 10 |
-----------------------------------------
```

in the button code I've just:

```
foreach (GridViewRow riga in gdDettaglio.Rows)
{
    if (riga.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        RadioButtonList rad = (RadioButtonList)riga.FindControl("rad");
        rad.SelectedValue = "True";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Doing the same thing on jquery work, it affects all the row:

```
    function accettaTutte() {
        $("#<%=gdDettaglio.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").each(function () {
            var items = $(this).find("[id$='radDaPa'] input:radio'");
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].value == 'True') {
                    if (!(items[i].checked)) {
                        items[i].checked = true;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

But I still need to do a foreach on that gridview, to update db, some idea on what could try to do? On every row I've also a "single row save" ImageButton, but clicking on it on the last two rows it's not firing the RowCommand event... It's like the two added GroupHeader rows are pushing out the last two data rows, no matter about the index.. If I click the ImageButton on the row with displayed (using Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex%>') rowIndex 2, in the rowCommand it become rowIndex 3, but it modified the right row, the one I've clicked.. If i do the same on row 7, it become 9.. But if forced it to get value on rowIndex 11, U'm getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException, because Rows.Count It's still 11..

Comment: Why not simply two GridViews ? If they are two different groups with different headers it also makes sense to split them visually, imo.

Comment: Good point, but I've showed just two group to simplify, actually I've 5 different groups.. And they have different headers (just to identify them and to have the collapsible function) but same 17 columns (they have one unique header in common on the top), so I prefer to use the same GridView, if possible..

Comment: Why do you have index 1 and 7 twice ? You need to know where the GroupHeaders are right ?

Comment: Because I assign the rowIndex to the GroupHeaders in the way I see on that article on the link, adding to the current rowIndex a variable that's increasing.. So it start processing row 0 and index is 1, that row belong to the first group (the dataset is order by the group), so 0 + index(1) = 1, and index++. Then it arrives at row 5, and it see that's changing group, then it add another GroupHeader and assign to it 5 + index(2) = 7. I don't know why, but if I modify this way to assign index to the GroupHeaders it don't show them in the right order on the grid, on top of own group..

Comment: You're right, using Add instead of AddAt make the index not relevant for the position, so now I'm using -1 and still have the right position of GroupHeaders..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now I am adding to the list that is GridView DataSource as many empty elements as are the GroupHeaders rows, so GridView.Rows.Count is enough to get all the rows..